# How to ignore food when it's not halal

Tags: halal-haram, work

I been working in a foreign country and they have meetings at hotel and dinner. But it's not halal but still chicken and beef. How can I escape such kind of food without making anyone offended or come underfire

Comment: _I'm a Muslim and I don't eat non-Halal food_ (?!)

Comment: @ozbek that will be rude. Sound rude?

Comment: Vegetarians say they don't eat meat products and no one says that's rude of them.

Comment: You can eat beef/chicken in western societies (McDonals/Burger King, etc.). It is halal since all of these establishment is owned by Christian/Jews of whom we are allowed to eat their food.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWW,

1) tell them you are a Muslim and only eat halal meat

2) ask for vegetarian only food.

3) Go on a vegetarian dies and say you are on a vegetarian diet

4) keep a fast. Then tell them you are fasting. They cant force you to eat.